# Creating a user directory based off an auto-incremented userID

Tags: php, mysqli, mkdir

I am attempting to create a user directory that's name is equal to the user's 'id' which is an auto-incremented column in my database. that will later be used to store text files for the user to access. But, Every time I run this I get an error because $row is null.

For context, This code is run right after a user is inserted into the database.

I've tried checking that $conn is valid and that $username is the correct username. However, when I run *createUserDir* on an existing user everything works fine.

Code for creating a user (works fine but thought I would show the placement of function call):

```
function createUser($conn, $email, $username, $pwd) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location: ../register.php?error=stmtfailure");
        exit();   
    }



    $hashpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $email, $hashpwd, $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    createUserDir($conn, $username);

    header("location: ../login.php?error=none");
    exit();
}
```

Creates a user directory:

```
function createUserDir($conn, $username) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location: ../register.php?error=stmtfailure");
        exit();   
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $stmtResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmtResult);
    
    $uid = $row['id'];
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    if(mkdir("../data/users/$uid")) {
        die('Failed to create user directory.');
    }
}
```

Comment: An easier way would be to retrieve the newly created user ID in your createUser function $stmt-> insert_id and pass that to creatUserDir this way you do not have sender another query to the DB and use your ID to create the directory

Answer (score 0):

while creating a record a**dd some text inside of the column, like "NA"** so it won't return an error and later update values in last, using *$last_id = $conn->insert_id;*
might sound silly but might be it will work